# mongodb community version support ssl

Tags: mongodb, ssl, parse-platform

i  have to configure on my server a mongodb that support ssl communication.

> Checking on the web i've seen this link http://tully.io/mongodb-ssl/
>   "Fortunately, MongoDB supports native SSL communication between itself
>   and connecting clients. Unfortunately, the community versions of
>   MongoDB are not built with such support, so one must either pay for
>   the MongoDB Enterprise service or build MongoDB themselves."

Checking on mongodb web site i've found a news :

> New in version 3.0: Most MongoDB distributions now include support for
>   SSL.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/

Is this true also for community version ? Or i have to follow the instrunctions reported in the first link ( compile mongo db ecc)

Thanks
Dario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using MongoDB community version *3.2.10* and this version support SSL mode. So it is true, Most MongoDB community distributions *>= 3.0* support SSL mode